# Vue Modal in foreach loop with laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel blade with a foreach loop successfully building a table with data, each row has a link to trigger a modal. My issue now is that when I click a link it triggers a modal on each row, and I want it to be specific to the clicked row AND show the info for that row within. Here's what I have now:

```
@section('content')

<div id="app">
<table class="uk-table uk-table-hover">
    <thead id="table-header">
        <tr>
            <th> Number</th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Updated</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($results as $result)
        <tr class="" id="">
            <td>
                <a id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">{{$result['number']}}</a>
                <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$result['name']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$result['updated']}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>


<!--  Modals  -->



<!-- End container -->
</div>
@endsection


@section('loadjs')
@include('js.datatables')

<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('modal',{
        template: '#modal-template'
    })

    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: { 
            showModal: false
        }
    })
</script>

<!-- Modals -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</script>

@endsection
```

What exactly do I need to change in order to make the modal correspond to the clicked row?

Comment: you need to accept `props` for modal and use those into your component template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily just take key of `$results` array in `foreach` loop and use it as following -

```
@section('content')

<div id="app">
<table class="uk-table uk-table-hover">
    <thead id="table-header">
        <tr>
            <th> Number</th>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Updated</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($results as $k => $result)
        <tr class="" id="">
            <td>
                <a id="show-modal" @click="showModal = {{$k}}">{{$result['number']}}</a>
                <modal v-if="showModal==={{$k}}" @close="showModal = false">
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$result['name']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$result['updated']}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>


<!-- End container -->
</div>
@endsection

....

<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('modal',{
        template: '#modal-template'
    })

    new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: { 
            showModal: false
        }
    })
</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I've worked with Vue, but it looks like you're binding whether or not a row shoes to a variable that all of the rows are going to be sharing. So when you set it true for one row, it sets it true for all of them and they open.

It might be better to rework your Modal component and move the logic for opening the rows into that so you aren't trying to manage so many rows directly from the table, if that makes sense.

Have each row (component) handle opening when clicked rather than trying to keep all of that logic on the table.